# What's the oldest and newest dates representable by PHP datetime?

Tags: php, datetime

Let's assume a 64 bit version of PHP in case that matters

I'm thinking about generating a random datetime but I realised I don't know how far back in time or how far forward in time the min-max possible values for datetime are to use as min-max for random

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45472389/571723

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3953343/571723

Comment: @dmikester1 that is 32 bits, not 64.

Comment: why would you go beyond/further 32bit ticks?

Comment: I don't think PHP's DateTime class has min/max values other than the hardware boundaries. However even on 32bit machines the dates are crazy big/small. The important thing is that it can easily work with dates much smaller than UNIX epoch. https://ideone.com/FGGoa3

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php

$min = \date_create('@' . PHP_INT_MIN);
var_dump($min->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

$max = \date_create('@' . PHP_INT_MAX);
var_dump($max->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

$diff = \date_diff($min, $max);

echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
```

https://3v4l.org/8N17M

This is the earliest and furthest datetime I've found so far

Not sure why I'm getting 0 days in the diff though

Comment: The difference between PHP_INT_MAX and PHP_INT_MIN is greater than PHP_INT_MAX. That may be why you're getting 0 days